# How to decide vectorization vs parallelization

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

How to decide vectorization vs parallelization? As an example:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def square(x):
    return x ** 2

N = 100000000
K = 10
x = np.random.normal(size=N)
begin = time.process_time()
x ** 2
print(time.process_time() - begin)
pool = Pool(K)
begin = time.process_time()
pool.map(square, list(range(N)))
pool.close()
print(time.process_time() - begin)

>> 0.4307680000000005
>> 27.385416
```

Vectorization is way faster in this case. Not sure if there will be exception. If not or 90% of the case vectorization is faster than parallelization, then I should always prioritize vectorize.

Comment: Your function is fairly simple, so multi-processing is slower as it requires setting up all the processes ... This is called overhead. With simple calculations the overhead eats up all speed gain. Try making your calculation much more complex. Than you will see a speed gain using multiple processes. However, numpy vectorization is well optimized.

Comment: Only way to tell is to benchmark.  It's highly machine and process dependant.  Generally processes that are a linear, dynamic, or few-in-one-out (your `square` function is linear one-in-one-out) will work better vectorized, while elliptical or many-in-many-out processes will be better in parallel.